# Add link on filter page of close vote queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design, vote-to-close

Building on [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208287/allow-direct-linking-to-a-filtered-review-queue), which added functionality to allow direct linking to specific filters in the close vote queue, I'd like to propose the next logical step:

Add a "link" button on the filter popup which generates the URL for that filter.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=programming-languages

Typing the URL by hand is a bit of effort, but more significantly - remembering the exact format, and that we have such functionality, is more difficult.